# Python : 'Page' object has no attribute 'getImageList' where I try to extract image from pdf

Tags: python, image, pdf

I try to extract some images from my pdf file, I used several methods but most of them were based on the Fitz library.

```
import fitz 
import io
from PIL import Image


pdf_file = fitz.open("my_file_pdf.pdf")


for page_index in range(len(pdf_file)):
    # get the page itself
    page = pdf_file[page_index]
    image_list = page.getImageList()
    # printing number of images found in this page
    if image_list:
        print(f"[+] Found  {len(image_list)} images in page {page_index}")
    else:
        print("[!] No images found on the given pdf page", page_index)
    for image_index, img in enumerate(page.getImageList(), start=1):
        print(img)
        print(image_index)
        # get the XREF of the image
        xref = img[0]
        # extract the image bytes
        base_image = pdf_file.extractImage(xref)
        image_bytes = base_image["image"]
        # get the image extension
        image_ext = base_image["ext"]
        # load it to PIL
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
        # save it to local disk
        image.save(open(f"image{page_index+1}_{image_index}.{image_ext}", "wb"))
```

This code gives me the error :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e5b882e88684> in <module>
     11     # get the page itself
     12     page = pdf_file[page_index]
---> 13     image_list = page.getImageList()
     14     # printing number of images found in this page
     15     if image_list:

AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'getImageList'
```

However according to the documentation this is the way to use this function so where could the problem come from?

Answer (score 4):

**Instead of `page.getImageList()` try using `page.get_images()`**

A list of attributes and methods belonging to the Page object is given at https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html.
getImageList() is not included however get_images() is.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at:
https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/znames.html

It seems that getImageList is a deprecated name. Here
you can find a list of new ones.

[image: Deprecated Names]